Could a planet only support underwater life?
I imagine the surface of Europa to be a barren atmospheric wasteland. But under the ice, acting as insulation, and where water meets soil, would it be warmer from geothermic heat to better support life?

Earth only had underwater life for 3 billion or more years.

I guess the interesting property this question is about is that energy is not coming (primarily) from the sun, but from something else like hydrothermal vents.

I'm really not sure what the question here is. Is the question "Is land life necessary for a biosphere"?  Is the question "Would the bottom of Europa's ocean be warmer than the top"?  I'd like to answer but I don't think I can as this is written.

Earth appears to support underwater life, cut off from the solar energy that powers the photosynthetic cycle we use. Powered by chemical reactions between hot water and minerals at subterranean hydrothermal vents, not only microbes but also macroscopic lifeforms, particularly tubeworms, may be found on the ocean floor far from the range where sunlight would penetrate. This scenario is considered as a model for possible life-sustaining conditions on several icy outer Solar System moons. From the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration:


Tubeworms that grow near the boundary where hot vent fluid mixes with cold seawater on the ocean floor are an example of extremophiles that broaden our perspective on where to look for life. Chemosynthetic bacteria living inside the tubeworms derive energy from chemicals emitted in the hot water of hydrothermal vents.

